# ctypes for mmapping and copying data

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ctypes

My goal is very simple. I want to use mmap to allocate a page of memory and then copy the hello world string into that memory page.

However I am getting a segmentation fault at the line `libc.memcpy(pageLoc, temp, ctypes.c_int(len(temp.value)))`

As I am still new to ctypes, I suspect it has something to do with me misusing a pointer. can anyone tell me why this is happening, and what I am doing wrong?

```
import ctypes

# initialize the ctype library
libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6")
pthread = ctypes.CDLL("libpthread.so.0")

# size of pages on system
PAGESIZE = ctypes.c_int(libc.getpagesize())

# allocate the page
pageLoc = ctypes.c_void_p(libc.mmap(0, PAGESIZE, 0x7, 0x22, 0, 0)) # defined in https://sites.uclouvain.be/SystInfo/usr/include/bits/mman.h.html
print "[*] Created a page in memory at address %s" % hex(pageLoc.value)

# copy hello world into the memory space
temp = ctypes.c_char_p("Hello world!\n\x00")
print hex(ctypes.c_void_p(
    libc.memcpy(pageLoc, temp, ctypes.c_int(len(temp.value)))
))

# free the page
libc.munmap(pageLoc, PAGESIZE)
```

Answer (score 1):

`ctypes` by default assumes all functions return `int`, which means that on a 64-bit machine, a returned pointer will get truncated to 32 bits, corrupting it.

To be safe, you should specify argument and result types for *every* libc function you call, as follows:

```
from ctypes import *
libc.getpagesize.argtypes = []
libc.getpagesize.restype = c_int
libc.mmap.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_size_t, c_int, c_int, c_int, c_long]
libc.mmap.restype = c_void_p
libc.memcpy.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_void_p, c_size_t]
libc.memcpy.restype = c_void_p
libc.munmap.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_size_t]
libc.munmap.restype = c_int
```

With these type definitions in place, your code works properly. Plus, it properly type-checks all the parameters and casts the return types for you, so you can remove the casts around your `libc` function calls.

Comment: Great answer but it may be worth mentioning that `ctypes` converts its basic types to python types. Even after `libc.mmap.restype = c_void_p`, the return value from this call is a python `int`,not a `c_void_p` object. The `int` can be used in the later `clib.mmap` call because its `argtypes` are also declared. This can be confusing when printing values.